# jQuery: How can I make a predefined color picker?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like that when I click on one of the colors of my color picker: http://prntscr.com/7rnafa the selected color changes on the targeted items.

I started to code the beginning of my code, but I need help for the rest.

**jQuery**:

```
$(function() {
    $(".colorPickerToggleButton").on("click", function(e) {
        $(".colorPickerToggleButton").toggleClass("active");
    });
    $('.colorPickerToggleButton').toggle(function() {
        $(".colorPicker").addClass("shown");
    });

    var color_elements_background = ".nodeList .categoryStrip";

    var color_elements_text = "a:link, a:visited";

    $(".colorPicker span").on("click", function() {
        var customColor = $(this).attr("custom_color");
    });
});
```

What I'd like to have exactly, it's that for example if I click one of the colors of my color picker, the clicked color is applied to the elements targeted. Example: http://prntscr.com/7rncra

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying your existing function to look like this:

```
$(".colorPicker span").on("click", function() {
    var customColor = $(this).attr("custom_color");
    $(color_elements_background).css("background-color", customColor);
    $(color_elements_text).css("color", customColor);
});
```

This will set the css colors on your targeted elements using jQuery.

The way it works is by passing your query strings directly into jQuery and letting it do the heavy lifting of selecting elements. Then it uses the [jQuery .css function](https://api.jquery.com/css/) to apply css styles to those elements.

Comment: Hi and thanks. Yes, but I need to target elements in my var: http://prntscr.com/7rnftq

Comment: @Uptop14 That's the idea. jQuery selects elements by passing in a string. So for instance when you pass the string "a:link, a:visited" into jQuery (by passing in the variable color_elements_text), it will operate on elements that match that query string. Usually people pass strings into jQuery as literals, but you can just as well pass them in by variable. That's what I did here. Edit: And because of how javascript closures work, the variable should be accessible from within the click function, if that was part of your question!

Comment: Okay. But how can I do if I've multiple colors? How I can use this? http://prntscr.com/7rnjcu

Comment: Not sure if I'm properly understanding your question, but if I am, I would give each one of your colorPicker spans a unique `custom_color` value. So your span would look sort of like this for instance: `<span custom_color="#FF0000">Color 1</span>`. That way, each span has the color embedded directly in the DOM element, which jQuery then reads using the `.attr` function and uses to set colors of other elements.

Comment: Hi, Maximillian. It is possible to save the user's selection in a cookie for the next visit? I use jQuery cookie plugin.

Comment: That is definitely possible! Try doing something like this when the user switches color: `$.cookie('site_color', customColor);`, then you can read it back in when the page loads using `$.cookie('site_color')`. Details here: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: I added this, but when I refresh my page, the custom color is removed. My code: http://prntscr.com/7rt60w

Comment: Post the code from that screenshot as a new Stack Overflow question - I'd love to keep helping, but I'm going to be busy today.

Comment: Okay, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31369747/jquery-cookie-how-can-i-save-the-color-selection-of-the-user-for-the-next-visit