# jQuery cookie: How can I save the color selection of the user for the next visit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm working on a jQuery predefined color picker. I'd like to save the color selection when the user click on one of the colors of my color picker: http://prntscr.com/7rnafa . To interact with cookies, I am using the jQuery plugin at https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie .

jQuery code:

```
var color_elements_background = ".nodeList .categoryStrip, .breadcrumb";

var color_elements_text = "a:link, a:visited";

$(".colorPicker span").on("click", function()
{
    var customColor = $(this).attr("custom_color");
    $(color_elements_background).css("background-color", customColor);
    $(color_elements_text).css("color", customColor);
});
});
```

HTML of my color picker:

```
                <div class="colorPicker">
                    <div class="colorPickerContent">
                        <div class="colorPickerItems">
                            <li>
                                <span custom_color="#FF0000">Color 1</span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span custom_color="#333333">Color 2</span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span custom_color="#FFFFFF">Color 3</span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span custom_color="#D0D0D0">Color 4</span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span custom_color="#CCCCCC">Color 5</span>
                            </li>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

See the plugin:

https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

To save a cookie using the Javascript library js.cookie you would use:

```
Cookies.set("color", customColor);
```

Also to get the value from the saved cookies would be:

```
var customColor = Cookies.get("color");
```

If you ever wanted to remove that cookie you would use:

```
Cookies.remove("color");
```

Comment: Hi and thanks. I'm using this: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie and I tried to add this: $.cookie('site_color', customColor); The color is not saved.

Answer (score -1):

Use the cookie library to store the previous selection, and populate the DOM using `$( document ).ready(function(){}`.

If your cookie is not saving, confirm the domain which the cookie is set. Often the cookie domain will not match your site when setting a cookie. Note that cookies will not save if you are using http://localhost. Use "Resources" tab within Chrome Dev tools to confirm your cookie is set.

Comment: I know, but I need the solution.

Comment: I've edited the solution. Confirm the domain which the cookie is being set.